# How do I detect certain things that I said in a speech recognizer script

Tags: python-3.x, voice-recognition

I am trying to make a voice activated virtual assistant of sorts using python, but I am not sure how to detect and distinguish between the different voice commands. Currently it just repeats back to you, "You Said [whatever i said]" but i want it to respond differently to different things that I say. I am quite new to python and don't know what I should do. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define what you want it to do. The last two lines of this tell the program to do something if the input is `hello`. So when you run it, you say "hello" and it will have a different response. If it does not detect that you said "hello" then it will not do anything. I might recommend finding a project on github where they have already done an assistant like this and start to try to understand what they did and edit to the specifications you want.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

sample_rate = 48000
chunk_size = 2048
r = sr.Recognizer()
device_id = 1

with sr.Microphone(device_index=device_id, sample_rate=sample_rate, chunk_size=chunk_size) as source:
    print("Say something...")
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.listen(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    if text.lower() == "hello":
        print("Hi, how are you?")
```